# Check integrity of MySQL database in app

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on an app using Codeigniter(PHP) and MySql(5.7.24); Multiple independent clients have this app installed on their servers. When there is an update/bugfix, we have an update server we push the changes onto: A zip file and an SQL file containing the update query. The clients can check if there's a new update and opt to install it by clicking on a button.

This is where we are facing an issue. Our update query can sometimes be large(creating a few new tables or adding some columns to the existing). Some clients have had their update interrupted midway(timeout or a server issue). This usually crashes their app or at least makes some features unusable due to the missing content from the database.
So, as a backup, I would like to have the updated database schema included with the app to compare with the database and generate a query to bring the database up to date.

What is the best way to go about doing this? Are there existing packages/libraries to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.